# UIMenuContoller UIMenuItem custom action with multiple parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I'm creating my custom UIMenuItem and adding it to shared UIMenuController's menuItems aray:

```
let menuItemCustom = UIMenuItem(title: "Custom action", action: "customAction:")
UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuItems = [menuItemCustom]
```

Then I enable standard `copy` action and my custom action in `canPerformAction` function:

```
func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return action == "copy:" || action == "customAction:"
}
```

Parameter that get passed to my custom action is UIMenuController:

```
func customAction(menuController: UIMenuController) {

}
```

Is there a way to pass **something else as a parameter**, or to have **multiple parameteres**? When I try to do something like this:

```
"customAction::"
```

my custom action simply gets ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions such as `"customAction:"` get wrapped into an Objective-C Selector.

You cannot pass additional parameters through Selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to pass the same `UIMenuController` twice using `"customAction:withObject:"`, which is not very helpful though. I solved what I was trying to achieve using delegation in the end.